# MySQL Query w/ Two Tables Filtering if Nonexistent from NULL to "" and if Multiple matches on joined table keep only most recent

Tags: mysql

So I have a table called "users" and a table called "shipping".
I want to create a query that will pull ALL "users" table info and JOIN from the "shipping" table the "tracking_number" and "tracking_date" columns only.  I want only the most recent "tracking_date" to show up per user.

To accomplish the above I wrote this (updated with Coalese per Paul's answer, thank you!):

```
SELECT users.*
     , shipping.tracking_number
     , coalese(shipping.tracking_date, '') AS `tracking_date`
  FROM users
  LEFT 
  JOIN shipping shipping
    ON users.user_id =shipping.user_id
```

<strike>The "shipping" table does not always have matches from the "users" table. The ones that do not have matches show as NULL for "tracking_number" and "tracking_date".</strike>

<strike>1.  I need the "tracking_date" column to show "" (blank) vs NULL.</strike>
2.  If one "user_id" has multiple "tracking_numbers" & "tracking_date" associated with them, then I need the most recent row only to show.

I tried using Max() but it shows only the MAX "tracking_date" from ALL records (not per User_ID)

I need to JSON encode it after (PHP) to create an API to get the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

example data:
table "users"

```
 user_id: 1 
 name: john smith
 address: 123 address road

 user_id: 2
 name: jane smith
 address: 456 address road

 user_id: 3
 name: john doe
 address 123 anon street

 user_id: 4
 name: jane doe
 address: 456 anon street
```

table "shipping"

```
 user_id: 1
 tracking_number: 1234567891
 tracking_date: 2020-06-17 12:34:56

 user_id: 2
 tracking_number: 1234567892
 tracking_date: 2020-07-10 12:34:56

 user_id: 1
 tracking_number: 1234567893
 tracking_date: 2020-07-17 12:34:56

 user_id: 4
 tracking_number: 1234567894
 tracking_date: 2020-08-11 12:34:56
```

Current results:

```
 user_id: 1 <-- user 1 shows twice
 name: john smith
 address: 123 address road
 tracking_number: 1234567891
 tracking_date: 2020-06-17 12:34:56

 user_id: 1  <-- user 1 shows twice (only need most current tracking date)
 name: john smith
 address: 123 address road
 tracking_number: 1234567893
 tracking_date: 2020-07-17 12:34:56

 user_id: 2
 name: jane smith
 address: 456 address road
 tracking_number: 1234567892
 tracking_date: 2020-07-10 12:34:56

 user_id: 3
 name: john doe
 address 123 anon street
 tracking_number: NULL
 tracking_date: 

 user_id: 4
 name: jane doe
 address: 456 anon street
 tracking_number: 1234567894
 tracking_date: 2020-08-11 12:34:56
```

Wanted results:

```
 user_id: 1 
 name: john smith
 address: 123 address road
 tracking_number: 1234567893
 tracking_date: 2020-07-17 12:34:56

 user_id: 2
 name: jane smith
 address: 456 address road
 tracking_number: 1234567892
 tracking_date: 2020-07-10 12:34:56

 user_id: 3
 name: john doe
 address 123 anon street
 tracking_number: NULL
 tracking_date: 

 user_id: 4
 name: jane doe
 address: 456 anon street
 tracking_number: 1234567894
 tracking_date: 2020-08-11 12:34:56
```

Comment: Hi, check the 'if_null' function, I think you can do what you requiere with that function.

Comment: kudos for providing sample data, but in future could you just use a simple table so it is easier to convert into sql inserts? (don't repeat column names and put each value into a new row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `coalesce()` which returns the first non-null value it encounters through the parameters going left to right. i.e. if the first parameter is NULL then return the second parameter which is the desired "" in this case.

```
SELECT users.*
     , coalesce(shipping.tracking_number,'""') as tracking_number
     , coalesce(shipping.tracking_date,'""') as tracking_date
  FROM users
  LEFT 
  JOIN shipping shipping
    ON users.user_id =shipping.user_id
```

There is a MySQL specific function `ifnull()` but I seriously suggest you stick to `coalesce()` which is ANSI standards compliant. `ifnull()` is limited to 2 parameters `coalesce()` allows more than 2 parameters.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull

For the issue of only retaining the most recent shipping reference, assuming you have MySQL 8, then I suggest use of `row_number() over()` which allows assigning the number 1 to the most recent date per user as shown below:

```
SELECT users.*
     , coalesce(shipping.tracking_number,'""') as tracking_number
     , coalesce(shipping.tracking_date,'""') as tracking_date
 FROM users
 LEFT 
 JOIN (
       SELECT user_id, tracking_number, tracking_date
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY tracking_date DESC) AS rn
       FROM shipping 
       ) AS shipping
   ON users.user_id =shipping.user_id
  AND shipping.rn = 1
```

This variant should work in older MySQL versions, prior to V8:

```
SELECT users.*
     , coalesce(shipping.tracking_number,'""') as tracking_number
     , coalesce(shipping.tracking_date,'""') as tracking_date
 FROM users
 LEFT 
 JOIN (
          SELECT
                 @row_num :=IF( @prev_value = s.user_id ,@row_num + 1 ,1 )AS rn
               , s.user_id, s.tracking_number, s.tracking_date
               , @prev_value := user_id
           FROM shipping As s
          CROSS
           JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='') vars
          ORDER
             BY s.user_id, s.tracking_date DESC
       ) AS shipping
   ON users.user_id =shipping.user_id
  AND shipping.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Paul Maxwell!  The coalesce function seemed to do the trick for NULL issue.

I still have the issue of the repeating Users

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use? Version 8 I hope.

Comment: added use of `row_number()` to my answer which will address "the most recent" problem as long as yu have MySQL 8 or above

Comment: Thank you so much Paul for expanding upon your answer. Unfortunately the DB is on MySQL 5. I tried using row_number but it didn’t work. 
Sadly the sys / net admin states he will not upgrade.

Comment: Always state version in tags or question - this will help answer your specific problem and subsequent readers too. It's why we ask oh so many times for version information ...

Comment: Shortly I will add another query variant that will work in pre V8 MySQL which mimics row_number.

Comment: An untested variant for older MySQL has been added. It's a common hack for MySQL that mimics row_number() before that better approach was available.

Comment: So I tried that and I am getting the error:
#1054 - Unknown column 's.tracking_date' in 'field list'

Comment: Run the inner subquery as a  standalone query. In that the alias s is used. Get that bit to work first. It will be nigh-on impossible for me to debug what you are doing through these comments, you have to carefully inspect any error messages and fix as needed

Comment: The query is working here *[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a293ac36724b9500271a2053b5b76c1f)*  if there are problems when you use it on your tables then check against the tables/columns I have used in that fiddle

Comment: I have been fiddling with this thing on PHPMyAdmin and I keep getting this error:
#1054 - Unknown column 'shipping.tracking_number' in 'field list'

Comment: NVM got it!  I misunderstood one part of the query while I was translating it.  
Thank you so much Paul Maxwell.  You are a genius!